# Dynamic split/row (by percentage) layout with CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm wondering if it's possible to have a multi-column split layout where every floating div has a dynamic width of 100%/n.

So if I have the following structure

```
<div id="mycontainer">
    <div class="split">
        LOREM
    </div>
    <div class="split">
        IPSUM
    </div>
</div>
```

the resulting css would be something like:

```
.split {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

.split:last-child {
    float: right;
}
```

where as

```
<div id="mycontainer">
    <div class="split">
        LOREM
    </div>
    <div class="split">
        IPSUM
    </div>
    <div class="split">
        DOLOR
    </div>
</div>
```

would result in

```
.split {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
}
```

and so on. I prefer plain CSS solutions, I know it's easily achievable with <strike>jQuery</strike> javascript in general.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A **pure CSS** solution would be to fake our `DIV` into our dear `table`, but hey, why not! It's a valid solution.

http://jsbin.com/amequw/1/edit

```
#mycontainer{
  background:#eee;
  padding:10px 0;
  display:table;      /* Fake :) */
  width:100%;
}
.split{
  background:#eee;
  display:table-cell; /* Act! */
}
```

and here's a demo with one `.split` less:

http://jsbin.com/amequw/2/edit

Comment: It seems that I need a container declaring `display: table`? And is this considered as good practice? Because it feels wrong somehow..

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using display: table, if you are concerned with support you can view: http://caniuse.com/css-table. I've used it several times when it's suited my situation, and it works really well.

Comment: @Atrotygma nothing bad about `table`. It's a `display` value like every other. The only difference is that it does the job pretty damn well

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Tried it out and I agree. Any thoughts about display: table besides display: flex (besides the part about browser support?)

Comment: @Atrotygma like you said: browser support AFAIK

Answer (score 2):

You could just use different classes for twocolumn, threecolumn, fourcolumn etc. So your CSS would look like something like this:

```
.column { float: left; }
.column-right { /* Just in case */ }

.twocolumn .column { width: 50%; }
.threecolumn .column { width: 33%; } 
 /* ... */
```

And your HTML like

```
<div class="twocolumn">
     <div class="column column-left">Split</div>
     <div class="column column-right">Split</div>
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="threecolumn">
     <div class="column column-left">Split</div>
     <div class="column">Split</div>
     <div class="column column-right">Split</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Flexible boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes) Not sure how supported they are at the moment but this will do what you want or `display: table`

Comment: Fantastic! Didn't know it was so widely supported, Only use it for my mobile stuffs :)

Comment: Bare in mind 43% of that is partial support, so it's not got that greater support. I wish it did though

Answer (score 0):

If you're after a pure CSS solution, then you probably want to use a grid setup such as [Foundation's](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html), which involves using a combination of predefined classes to layout your elements.

Answer (score -1):

try using javascript/jquery to count the number of splits

```
var numItems = $('.split').length;

var percentage = 100/numItems;

$(".split").css("width",percentage+"%");
```

i've not tested the code but maybe worth a go

Comment: I think the OP wanted a pure CSS solution.

Comment: You would probably want to `floor` the percentage as the last element would be popped off with 3/5/7 items, etc since the float would be *just* above exact.

Comment: yeah i gathered, just though i would give options

Comment: I would also advise that this will __only__ work when using `box-sizing: border-box;` since __any__ margin or padding will break this.